# Solution of working with two stacks

Tags: python, math, stack

I am trying the problem of equal stacks from Hackerrank : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks/problem.

Can someone please help me understand the difference in the logic of below two codes. While the first one fails the other one succeeds:

First(My solution):

```
n1, n2, n3 = map(int, input().split())
H1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
H2 = list(map(int, input().split()))
H3 = list(map(int, input().split()))

sum_h1 = sum(H1)
sum_h2 = sum(H2)
sum_h3 = sum(H3)
#print (sum_h1,sum_h2,sum_h3)

while not (sum_h1 == sum_h2 and sum_h2 == sum_h3):
    if sum_h1 > sum_h2 or sum_h1 > sum_h3:
        #t = H1.pop()
        sum_h1 -= H1[0]
        #print ("Checking:",sum_h1)
    if sum_h2 > sum_h1 or sum_h2 > sum_h3:
        #t = H2.pop()
        sum_h2 -= H2[0]
    if sum_h3 > sum_h1 or sum_h3 > sum_h2:
        #t = H3.pop()
        sum_h3 -= H3[0]
print (sum_h1)
```

Second solution(correct):

```
n1, n2, n3 = map(int, input().split())
H1 = list(map(int, input().split()))[::-1]
H2 = list(map(int, input().split()))[::-1]
H3 = list(map(int, input().split()))[::-1]

sum_h1 = sum(H1)
sum_h2 = sum(H2)
sum_h3 = sum(H3)
#print (sum_h1,sum_h2,sum_h3)

while not (sum_h1 == sum_h2 and sum_h2 == sum_h3):
    if sum_h1 > sum_h2 or sum_h1 > sum_h3:
        t = H1.pop()
        sum_h1 -= t
    if sum_h2 > sum_h1 or sum_h2 > sum_h3:
        t = H2.pop()
        sum_h2 -= t
    if sum_h3 > sum_h1 or sum_h3 > sum_h2:
        t = H3.pop()
        sum_h3 -= t
print (sum_h1)
```

I know in the second one we are reversing the input array . But should that make any difference.

I am completely puzzled.

Please help me in pointing out what is the issue with the first code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Order matters

> I know in the second one we are reversing the input array . But should that make any difference.

**Yes** that **makes a difference**. Say you have the following stacks:

```
1
1  2  1
1  1  3
```

Now we can simply pop the `1` (in boldface) from the right stack, and all stacks have the same height.

But the opposite is *not* true. If the stacks are reversed:

```
1
1  1  3
1  2  1
```

We have to pop the right stack, since it is the largest one. But we can only pop `3` (in boldface) from it. As a result the maximum height can only be `1`. When we pop the `3`, we will later discover, that the maximum equal height we can obtain is `0`. If we pop the right stack we obtain:

```
1
1  1
1  2  1
```

But the stack in the middle has a 2 at the bottom. So we can never produce a 1 as sum of the stack in the middle.

A stack implies an *order*: we have to remove the elements above a cylinder, before we can pop that element, so the order matters.

## Why the first does not work.

In the first code fragment, you subtract the first element from the sum of that stack. But you do **not delete that element** from the list. As a result, you keep popping the *first* element from the stack.

You can fix it by `pop(0)` (popping from the beginning of the list), or deleting that element later:

```
# fix of the first code fragment

while not (sum_h1 == sum_h2 and sum_h2 == sum_h3):
    if sum_h1 > sum_h2 or sum_h1 > sum_h3:
        sum_h1 -= H1.pop(0)
        #print ("Checking:",sum_h1)
    if sum_h2 > sum_h1 or sum_h2 > sum_h3:
        sum_h2 -= H2.pop(0)
    if sum_h3 > sum_h1 or sum_h3 > sum_h2:
        sum_h3 -= H3.pop(0)
```

Or:

```
# fix of the first code fragment

while not (sum_h1 == sum_h2 and sum_h2 == sum_h3):
    if sum_h1 > sum_h2 or sum_h1 > sum_h3:
        sum_h1 -= H1[0]
        del H1[0]
        #print ("Checking:",sum_h1)
    if sum_h2 > sum_h1 or sum_h2 > sum_h3:
        sum_h2 -= H2[0]
        del H2[0]
    if sum_h3 > sum_h1 or sum_h3 > sum_h2:
        sum_h3 -= H3[0]
        del H3[0]
```

But mind that these are **inefficient**: popping from the start is a *O(n)* operation with *n* the size of the list.

Comment: Your logic is right, except in OP's solution he's indexing `H[0]`, so he's still subtracting 1. I don't think the order is the issue. OP isn't calling `H.pop(0)`.

Comment: @Coldspeed: but `pop()` pops from the right of the list (so the top of the stack). That's why the first fails whereas the second succeeds.

Comment: `pop(0)` pops from the start. And in OP's case with the stacks reversed, `pop(0)` is the right operation, which OP isn't doing (from what I see). `>>> x = [1, 2, 3];
>>> x.pop(0); 
1`

Comment: @Coldspeed: I did not notice the lists were not reversed in the first code fragment. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Since @Willem Van Onsem and @coldspeed explained how the first solution is different from the other I thought I could explain a similar solution that could be easier to understand (in my opinion).

Let's say the stacks are as in the original problem:

```
3 2 1 1 1  (stack1)
4 3 2      (stack2)
1 1 4 1    (stack3)
```

Here, the left most number is a top of each stack and the right most is the bottom. I pick the first stack as a reference stack (but it can be any of the three). Its possible heights when removing cylinders are `8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0`. The task is to try out all the heights and see if they could be common ones. Then, the maximum common height is the answer.

Let's solve the problem from bottom to top. So, the stacks are empty and we want to build them from the beginning. While building them we'll find all the stack configurations for which their heights are equal. So, the configuration with the maximum height  will be an answer to the question.

1. Initially maximum common height as well as current heights for each stack are  `0`

   ```
   0
   0
   0
   0 (max)
   ```
2. Add `1` to `stack1`'s height. Then, because the current height of `stack2` is less than that of `stack1` keep increasing it by summing the bottom elements. Do the same for `stack3`

   ```
   1
   2
   1
   0 (max)
   ```

   Since the heights are different max remains `0`. So, `1` can't be a common height for the stacks.
3. Add `1` to `stack1`'s height. `stack2`'s height is equal so do nothing for it. For `stack3` keep summing up as long as the height is less.

   ```
   2
   2
   5
   0 (max)
   ```
4. ```
   3
   5
   5
   0 (max)
   ```
5. ```
   3
   5
   5
   0 (max)
   ```
6. ```
   5
   5
   5
   5 (max)
   ```
7. ```
   8
   9
   10
   5 (max)
   ```
8. Output the max height as the first stack is empty and it doesn't make sense to work with other stacks (if they're still non-empty).

   ```
   5 (max)
   ```

Now, the algorithm itself (in `Python3` for simplicity):

```
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
stack1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
stack2 = list(map(int, input().split()))
stack3 = list(map(int, input().split()))

max_height = 0
height1 = 0
height2 = 0
height3 = 0

while len(stack1) > 0:
    if len(stack1) > 0:    
        height1 += stack1.pop() 
    while len(stack2) > 0 and height2 < height1:
        height2 += stack2.pop()        
    while len(stack3) > 0 and height3 < height1:
        height3 += stack3.pop()  

    if height1 == height2 == height3:
        max_height = height1     

print (max_height)
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your solution and the correct one is that your stacks are reversed. In this case, you should be calling `list.pop(0)` to remove the first element.

```
while not (sum_h1 == sum_h2 and sum_h2 == sum_h3):
    if sum_h1 > sum_h2 or sum_h1 > sum_h3:
        t = H1.pop(0) # -------------- pop 0th element 
        sum_h1 -= t  
    if sum_h2 > sum_h1 or sum_h2 > sum_h3:
        t = H2.pop(0)  # -------------- pop 0th element 
        sum_h2 -= t
    if sum_h3 > sum_h1 or sum_h3 > sum_h2:
        t = H3.pop(0)  # -------------- pop 0th element 
        sum_h3 -= t
print (sum_h1)
```

For this input:

```
5 3 4
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
```

This is the output:

```
5
```